# Creating an Open Function in Java using JFIleChooser

Tags: java, swing, file, user-interface

Hi i was having issues completetly understanding this feature of my notepad. I want the user ot search for any .txt file they desire in their directory and be able to open it. Remember this is a notepad so the file must be readeable and writable. I created the simple Open but i get stuck in the fact that i keep getting red in br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(open));, Only on the new FileReader(open)); part. How can i fix this? Any help is appreciated.
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

```
    if(event.getSource() == this.newFile){
        this.textarea.setText("");

    }else if(event.getSource() == this.openFile){
        JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
        int option = open.showOpenDialog(this);
        FileReader fr;
        BufferedReader br;

        if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(open)); 
                //while(){

                //}

            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening files with JFileChooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283455/opening-files-with-jfilechooser)

Answer (score 1):

`JFileChooser` is not a `File`, it can not be used as a parameter to `FileReader`, instead, you need to get the selected `File` from the chooser...

```
File choosenOne = open.getSelectedFile();
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(choosenOne ));
```

There are options available to you to make your life a little easier, like filters.

Check out [How to use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly fast reply :D i was able to fix my problem